# HTML.DropDownListFor class assignment

Tags: asp.net, class, variable-assignment, html.dropdownlistfor

Is it possible to assign my own class to the HTML.DropDownListFor() helper?

Comment: What do you mean by "assign [a] class to" the helper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the overloaded method has an `object htmlAttributes` as last parameter in which you can specify extra attributes to be added to the generated html:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(..., new { "class" = "myclassname" };
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee703670.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Didier's answer is mostly correct, but to define a class value in htmlAttributes object, you need to use this syntax:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(..., new { @class = "myclassname" } );
```

The "@" is to let the compiler know that this is not the keyword "class".  Using `"class"`  will result in a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the below logic.

```
@Html.DropDownList("CourseId", new List<SelectListItem>(), new {@class="myclassname"} )
```

OR

```
@Html.DropDownList("CourseId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CourseId, new { @class="myclassname" })
```

OR

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CourseId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CourseId, new { @class = "myclassname" })
```