# Adding a class to HTML.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to add a class assignment to the following line of code,

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Business, new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{
                   new { ... },
                   new { ... },
                   new { ... }
                },
              "value",
              "text",
              2))
```

One answer given on this site ([HTML.DropDownListFor class assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970701/html-dropdownlistfor-class-assignment)) suggested adding it as an overload method that takes a 'object htmlAttributes' as the last parameter. However, I can not see this parameter as an option so I'm a bit confused how this is possible.

In my example I am using every overload method possible and there is none for htmlattributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Four of the [DropDownListFor overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx) have HTML Attributes as their last parameter. [This one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703573(v=vs.118).aspx) is probably the easiest. Modifying your example, it becomes:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Business, 
                      new SelectList(
                          new List<Object>{
                              new { ... },
                              new { ... },
                              new { ... }
                          },
                          "value",
                          "text",
                          2),
                      new {
                          @class = "myclass"
                      })
```

Comment: Thanks, I was stupidly trying to add it in within the actual select statement part. This works great now.

Answer (score 2):

Use following overload:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

Here is [MSDN docs of the overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703436(v=vs.118).aspx://)

do this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Business, 
                      new SelectList(new List<Object>
                                 { 
                                  new { ... },
                                  new { ... },
                                  new { ... } 
                                }, 
                                "value", "text", 2),
                     new { @class ="YourClass"})
```

or following overload will also work:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
string optionLabel,
IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Business, 
                      new SelectList(new List<Object> 
                                        { 
                                         new { ... }, 
                                         new { ... },
                                        }, "value", "text", 2), 
                      null,new { @class ="YourClass"})
```

[MSDN docs of the overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703567(v=vs.118).aspx://)